# smooth-scrolling ListView in android

Tags: android, listview

I'm having some problems getting smoothScrollBy(int distance, int duration) to work. What I'm trying to do is to center an item in the middle of the listview when user scrolls the listview. There are only 3 visible items at a time, so when user scrolls, the item nearest the center should be smooth-scrolled to, instead of using setSelectionFromTop (which works).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you right but maybe you could try smooth-scrolling to the item above the center one?

Comment: smooth-scrolling doesn't do anything for me, not sure why. Is it because it's in touch-mode (because the user has scrolled by touching the view)? The only thing that DOES seem to work is setSelectionFromTop. Also, I'm developing for 2.2.

Comment: Sorted. Needed to use a handler.. :)